# How to map a foreign key name on table with composite key?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to set the foreign key constraint name that is autogenerated by hibernate, so that is not named `fk_123213241341`, but `fk_user`.

I'm trying to use the new JPA 2.1 Annotation `@ForeignKey`. But I'm missing probably something:

`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering User from Trip has the wrong number of column. should be 2`

```
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
class User {
    @Id
    String firstname;

    @Id
    String lastname;

    //other fields omitted
}

class UserPK {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
}

class Trip {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: what did you try to make? `User` have `id.firstname` and `id.lastname` which in object `UserPK`. then many `trip` can have one `User`. so inside trip you can get `user.id.firstname` and `user.id.lastname`. Something like this?

Comment: and you only want to use `@ForeignKey` not `@JoinColumns`

Comment: `@ForeignKey`is deprecated since latest hibernate version which depends on JPA 2.1

Comment: yup, cz @javax.persistence.ForeignKey in JPA 2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `@JoinColumns` annotation (note the `'s'`):

```
class Trip {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: Hm that does not work: `The annotation @JoinColumns must define the attribute value`

Comment: Ok got it: `@JoinColumns (foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER"), value = {
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "firstname"),
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "lastname")
    })`